# How to match a string that doesn't include a substring?

Tags: expl3, l3regex

I need a regular expression for `\regex_replace_all` that matches a string that starts with `A`, ends with `B`, and doesn't contain `CBC` inside. This one doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\foo{foo A xxxx B bar}
\regex_replace_all:nnN { A ((?!CBC).)+ B }{ replaced } \foo
\foo
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I expect it to render `foo replaced bar`. However, no replacement happens.
To my knowledge `A ((?!CBC).)+ B` is a correct regexp. I see this in the log:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unknown special group '(?! ...' in a regular expression.
```

Comment: The `interface3` doc says: *"The syntax of regular expressions is **mostly** a subset of the PCRE syntax (and **very close** to POSIX), with some additions due to the fact that TEX manipulates tokens rather than characters."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\foo{foo A xxxx B bar}
\regex_replace_all:nnN {A([^C]*(C[^B]|CB[^C])?)*B  }{ replaced } \foo
\foo
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I think this regex works better: `A([^C]*(C[^B]|CB[^C])?)*B`

Comment: @yegor256 sorry yes, I'll fix